# Not getting the Token in Azure API Apps - ADAL

Tags: adal

I have created a API where I am trying to get token & then getting the data using that token
Its working fine in Visual Studio debug mode/locally, Prompting for User Credential, as MFA is enabled , also OTP will be asked and working fine

Problem is when I deploy in Azure API/WEb apps, its not working and failing at the line where getting the token. Also noticed, it never prompts for USer credential while deployed in web app. I want to get the Token silently if not possible, Prompting for credential also OK. Atleast it should work after deeployment in web app. Here the Code snippet:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;

//API Method
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        try
        {
    private static string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}" ,"575d120d-78ae-41fc-b5a0-4072a4349b");

    AuthenticationResult result = null;
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientId, redirectUri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));//new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto)
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
            // Call the To Do list service.
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(todoListBaseAddress + "locations");//+ "/api/values/4"
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(response.RequestMessage.ToString());
                string s = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }

  }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            return new string[] { ex.Message, ex.StackTrace };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new string[] { ex.Message, ex.StackTrace };
        }
    }
```

Comment: please update your question with the error you are getting when token acquisition fails.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure both applications are [registered in Azure AD and user consent has been granted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#register-the-application-and-service-in-azure-ad) for the on-behalf-of flow.

For silent token acquisition, follow [the recommended pattern](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token#recommended-pattern-to-acquire-a-token) and call `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` first and fall-back to `AcquireTokenAsync` only upon failure.